# Windows 7 WebDAV cookie management

Tags: windows-7, webdav, webclient

We have a problem where cookies are persisting on Windows 7 Webclient which connects to a WebDAV share.

Does anyone know where these cookies are stored? Is it the Temporary Internet Files? Or is it elsewhere... also how do you kill these cookies by passing headers into the webclient?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they are stored in either the Stored Credentials in Control Panel.